# I am not getting the proper output in C program?

Tags: c

I am using the ***Dev-c++*** and ***Code::Blocks*** IDE for the C program.I want to loop up to 10 times from the user.But I am not getting the proper output.First time I am 
getting the proper output after that from second time I am not getting the proper output.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
char g;
int yos,qual,sal,a = 1;
printf("\nEnter M for Male and F for Female");
printf("\nEnter 0 for Graduate and 1 for Post-Graduate");

while(a<=10) {
    printf("\n\n\nEnter  gender, year of service , qualification : ");
    scanf("%c%d%d",&g,&yos,&qual);
    if(g=='M' && yos>=10 && qual==1)
    sal = 15000;
    else if((g=='M' && yos>=10 && qual==0) || (g=='M' && yos<10 && qual==1))
        sal = 10000;
    else if(g=='M' && yos<10 && qual==0)
        sal = 7000;
    else if(g=='F' && yos>=10 && qual==1)
        sal = 12000;
    else if(g=='F' && yos>=10 && qual==0)
        sal = 9000;
    else if(g=='F' && yos<10 && qual==1)
        sal = 10000;
    else if(g=='F' && yos<10 && qual==0)
        sal = 6000;
    printf("\nSalary of the employee is : %d",sal);
        a++;
    }

}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Why you didn't put year of service and qualification in second time?

Comment: Because when he hit `enter` it just printed out the salary instead of waiting for more input

Comment: check the return value of `scanf`. values aren't changed in the second time.

Comment: The 2nd call consumes the <Enter> from the first entry into `g`.  Your first call to `scanf()` did not have a previous <Enter>` to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

Two things. Putting a `space` before `%c` in `scanf()` will eat up any whitespace before it, and checking for the correct number of inputs returned by `scanf()` will guard against silly output. I entered the first set with `newline` separator, the second set with `space` separater.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char g;
    int yos, qual;

    printf("\nEnter char, int, int: ");
    if (3 != scanf(" %c%d%d", &g, &yos, &qual))
        printf ("Error\n");
    else
        printf("You entered: %c %d %d\n", g, yos, qual);

    printf("\nEnter char, int, int: ");
    if (3 != scanf(" %c%d%d", &g, &yos, &qual))
        printf ("Error\n");
    else
        printf("You entered: %c %d %d\n", g, yos, qual);

    return 0;
}
```

Program input/output

```
Enter char, int, int: a
1
2
You entered: a 1 2

Enter char, int, int: b 6 7
You entered: b 6 7
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
scanf("%c%d%d",&g,&yos,&qual);
```

the second time the statement is executed, the newline character is read into `g`. To prevent newlines and white spaces to be read into `g`, use:

```
scanf(" %c%d%d",&g,&yos,&qual);
//    ^^ Add a space
```

Personally, I prefer to put spaces around the other format specifiers too.

```
scanf(" %c %d %d", &g, &yos, &qual);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `scanf()` format.  Most format descriptors implicitly skip leading whitespace, but the `%c` does not (so that it can be used to *read* whitespace).  Furthermore, `scanf()` reads characters as long as they can be matched to the format, and leaves unread any that cannot be matched.  Consider this, then:

```
    scanf("%c%d%d",&g,&yos,&qual);
```

On the first iteration, it

1. reads the 'M' into variable `g`,
2. skips the whitespace (a newline) before the first number
3. reads the digit string "10" (up to but not including the newline), converts it to an integer, and stores it in `yos`,
4. skips the whitespace (a newline) before the next number
5. reads the digit string "1" (up to but not including the newline), converts it to an integer, and stores it in `qual`.

At that point, the next character waiting in the input is a newline.

On the second iteration, *the newline* is scanned into variable `g`, and `scanf()` tries to match an integer starting with the *next* character ('M').  This fails, so `scanf()` is done, and your program proceeds to print its output.

It's a bit tricky to do interactive input with `scanf()`, but you would do a bit better with a slight modification to your format:

```
scanf(" %c%d%d",&g,&yos,&qual);
```

Moreover, you should always check the return value to verify that `scanf()` has successfully matched all the expected fields (it returns the number of fields successfully matched, or `EOF` on error or if the end of the input is reached before any field is matched).